# 'Until 17th January' includes 17th or doesn't include?

Tags: dates

When preceding the word 'until' before a date, does it include this date or it excludes this date?

For example:

> The first semester classes will be from 1st September **Until 17th** January.

Does it **include** classes on **17th** or the last class is on **16th**?

Comment: Commonsense suggests that if the last class was on the 16th, they would have said 'until 16 January'.

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be intended to include the 17th, but there is some doubt - so it's common to write

> > The first semester classes will be from 1st September until 17th January **(inclusive)**

to be absolutely clear that there are classes on both 1st September and 17th January.

You can write

> > The first semester classes will be from 1st September until 17th January **(exclusive)**

If there are no classes on the first and last dates listed, but I don't know of an easy way to include one date but not the other without adding more words.